# Microsoft Exchange: How to get AD domain via EWS?

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchangewebservices

I get an Exchange email address, and I have to fetch the AD entry of the user with that email address.

As long as I only have one GC, this works fine using DirectoryEntry:

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("GC:"));
searcher.Filter = string.Format("{0}={1}","mail","alexander@contoso.com");
DirectoryEntry entry = searcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry();
```

But if I have multiple trusted GCs, and the user that is querying AD is in a different GC than the user queried, **the object cannot be found in the global catalog**, because I did not provide the AD domain to search in.

So either I query all GCs (can I find all trusted GCs in a GC?) or I get the DirectoryEntry using EWS.

Which of these two possibilities would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean:

> But if I have multiple trusted GCs, and the user that is querying AD
>   is in a different GC than the user queried, the object cannot be found
>   in the global catalog, because I did not provide the AD domain to
>   search in.

A GC only contains objects in its own forest.
You cannot find a user located in forest1 by querying a GC in forest2.

To specify the GC to use

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(
    new DirectoryEntry("GC://forest1.net/"));
```

You may need to provide credential of another user if current user don't have permission to read from that forest:

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(
    new DirectoryEntry("GC://forest1.net/", "user", "password"));
```

Comment: And how do I get `forest1.net` from a mail address? I can't assume that all users with mail address `xy@forest1.net` are in ActiveDirectory domain `forest1.net`, because they are to be moved to `forest2.com`, but will keep their old `@forest1.net`email address. And this is where it gets nasty...

Comment: If you only have email address, by AD, i'm afraid you have to search one GC per forest. But i'm not familiar with EWS. EWS may provide some better way to do so...

Comment: How do I obtain a list of all available forests, then?

Comment: Alexander, have you looked at EWS ResolveName method?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.resolvename(v=exchg.80).aspx Thanks.